# Multiple Route Location Blocks PHP Access with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

I am having issues to get multiple location blocks to work with the below configurations. The objectives are `/api` will route into the PHP endpoints and `/phpmyadmin` will route into PhpMyAdmin pages.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          root /usr/share/;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
          root /usr/share/;
        }
    }

    location /api {
      alias /var/www/html/api/src/public;
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri  /index.php?$query_string;
    }


      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      }
}
```

The PhpMyAdmin is working but Nginx return 404 when access with `/api`. The logs are shown below. However, the `index.php` is definitely exist in `/var/www/html/api/src/public`.

```
[14/Jul/2021:06:47:24 +0800] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
```